# Is it possible to bypass internet ban?

Tags: centos, vpn

When I ping google.com or any domain I see real IP but time-outs. and ip address outside of Iran can not be reached. It seems that they have to let the request send and receive IP to resolve international domains. so send and receive to worldwide is doing this way. right? It is possible to have internet access through this way to send and receive data?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a problem that you can solve with UNIX/Linux...

Comment: for who want to know why i'm asking thus question, I want to bypass iran internet ban even if can have a low speed.

Comment: can't you jsut use a vpn? tor?

Comment: HTTP over DNS is a thing apparently: https://medium.com/@galolbardes/learn-how-easy-is-to-bypass-firewalls-using-dns-tunneling-and-also-how-to-block-it-3ed652f4a000, but I have no idea to implement it

Comment: no, can't connect tor, openvpn,open connect or any other vpn :(

Comment: read here https://www.softether.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinging dns names will probably return the correct IP address due to a dns nameserver cache. Basically you proxy a global or national dns name server, that has these IP addresses stored which are returned via ping.

In a rudimentary way you are asking an address book (DNS) where google lives and you get the phone number back, but googles phone is blocked by your provider.

You are not allowed to call the number, because you have no credit, or your Mullah does not allow it!

So to answer your question: " ... is it ... possible to have internet access through this way to send and receive data?"

Possibly not, but there are ways to piggy back on dns via dns tunnels for an internet connection as @muru pointed out in his comment above.

See this article @muru posted:

> https://medium.com/@galolbardes/learn-how-easy-is-to-bypass-firewalls-using-dns-tunneling-and-also-how-to-block-it-3ed652f4a000

That said, I assume they prevent dns tunneling, but there is not enough information to affirm or deny that assumption.